# How to get the content of https with or without curl?

Tags: php, curl

Can anybody tell me that how to fetch the content of https using curl or without curl?

Comment: Without cURL, you could use `openssl s_client -connect servername:port`

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Can You please give me the complete code..

Comment: @BhavnishNarang it is a commandline command that talks to an SSL host in the same way Telnet talks to a plain host. I leave it up to you to implement the rest. Hint: you'll have to implement the HTTP protocol yourself.

Comment: @rikesh: i tried nothing bro...i want the complete code

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);   what we have to write in username and password...